# Button constructor doesn't seems to allow local variable

Tags: ios, swiftui

Why this code would not compile?
it says "Generic parameter 'Label' could not be inferred"

```
struct ReadyToEatListX: View {
  var body : some View{
    Button(action: {}){
      let text = "Hello, World"  
      return Text(text)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is fixed variant, just help compiler to understand what type is provided for Label

```
struct ReadyToEatListX: View {
  var body : some View {
    Button(action: {}) { () -> Text in // << here !!
      let text = "Hello, World"
      return Text(text)
    }
  }
}
```